# Moving a movieclip with another movieclip in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

How can we move a movieclip in the direction another movieclip moving?  I have a movieclip, the prey, that is moving with accelerometer updates. And I want the follower movieclip to catch up that movieclip like a prey. The prey is moving with accelerometer changes. I want the follower movieclip to follow prey. Can this be done?

Comment: You move e.g. movieclip1 and movieclip2 should move in the same direction?

Comment: I removed the AS2 tag if you don't mind, it made a proper markup of the code part of my answer impossible. Also it's irrelevant to the question since you say you want to use AS3 for it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple way of having one clip chase another. Copy paste this into a new fla file and compile it to see the results.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var mcOne : MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcOne.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000 );
mcOne.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 10 );
mcOne.speedX = 1.9;
mcOne.speedY = 1.9;
addChild( mcOne );

var mcTwo : MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcTwo.graphics.beginFill( 0xFF0000 );
mcTwo.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 10 );
mcTwo.speedX = 2;
mcTwo.speedY = 2;
addChild( mcTwo );

moveClipsToRandomPosition( mcOne );
moveClipsToRandomPosition( mcTwo );

stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame );

function onStageEnterFrame( evt : Event ) : void
{
    moveMC( mcOne );
    chase( mcTwo, mcOne );
    checkBounds( mcOne );
}

function chase( chasingMC : MovieClip, chasedMC : MovieClip ) : void
{
    if( chasingMC.x < chasedMC.x )
    {
        if( chasingMC.x + chasingMC.speedX > chasedMC.x )
        {
            chasingMC.x = chasedMC.x;
        }
        else
        {
            chasingMC.x += chasingMC.speedX;
        }
    }
    else if( chasingMC.x > chasedMC.x )
    {
        if( chasingMC.x - chasingMC.speedX < chasedMC.x )
        {
            chasingMC.x = chasedMC.x;
        }
        else
        {
            chasingMC.x -= chasingMC.speedX;
        }
    }

    if( chasingMC.y < chasedMC.y )
    {
        if( chasingMC.y + chasingMC.speedY > chasedMC.y )
        {
            chasingMC.y = chasedMC.y;
        }
        else
        {
            chasingMC.y += chasingMC.speedY;
        }
    }
    else if( chasingMC.y > chasedMC.y )
    {
        if( chasingMC.y - chasingMC.speedY < chasedMC.y )
        {
            chasingMC.y = chasedMC.y;
        }
        else
        {
            chasingMC.y -= chasingMC.speedY;
        }
    }

    if( chasingMC.y == chasedMC.y && chasingMC.x == chasedMC.x )
    {
        trace( "ChasingMC caught chasedMC" );
        moveClipsToRandomPosition( mcOne );
        moveClipsToRandomPosition( mcTwo );
    }
}

function moveClipsToRandomPosition( mc : MovieClip ) : void
{
    mc.x = ( Math.random() * ( stage.stageWidth - 20 ) ) + 10;
    mc.y = ( Math.random() * ( stage.stageHeight - 20 ) ) + 10;
}

function moveMC( mc : MovieClip ) : void
{
    mc.x += mc.speedX;
    mc.y += mc.speedY;
}

function checkBounds( mc : MovieClip ) : void
{
    if( ( mc.x + mc.width / 2 ) >= stage.stageWidth )
    {
        mc.speedX *= -1;
    }
    else if( ( mc.x - mc.width / 2 ) <= 0 )
    {
        mc.speedX *= -1;
    }

    if( ( mc.y + mc.height / 2 ) >= stage.stageHeight )
    {
        mc.speedY *= -1;
    }
    else if( ( mc.y - mc.height / 2 ) <= 0 )
    {
        mc.speedY *= -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let movieclip #2 follow the first one like this:

```
//this would usually be in an ENTER_FRAME event since there's no tweening going on here
//mc1 is your first movieclip, mc2 the second
mc1.x += 20; //this is the first one that needs to be followed
mc2.x = (mc1.x - 40); //this is the follower; it's always 40px horizontally behind mc1
```

Also, you could use a 'container' sprite. This is an empty sprite that you add other Sprites or MovieClips into. It works like this:

```
myContainerVar.addChild(mc1); //myContainerVar is a(n empty) Sprite.
myContainerVar.addChild(mc2);
myContainerVar.x += 20; //this moves both movieclips.
//make sure you do this INSTEAD of the normal addChild(m1);!
```

What I'm doing here is adding `mc1` and `mc2` into `myContainerVar`. Changes such as moving the `myContainerVar` variable will then automatically apply to `mc1` and `mc2` as well.

One small sidenote: if you go into this a bit more advanced, you should know that statistically, the positions of mc1 and mc2 do not change when changing the positions of myContainerVar. Beware ;)

Comment: Thanks poepje, for the quick response. Actually the scenario is this, that, I have a movieclip that is moving with accelerometer updates. And I want the follower movieclip to catch up that movieclip like a prey. Can this be done? The prey can move in any direction

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by 'accelerometer'? This word/method is completely unknown to me :p

Comment: I would guess that this is a flex mobile app using the phone's accelerometer. Accelerometer provides feedback of how fast the phone is moving from left to right, up and down, and tilt.

Comment: Thanks Dom, and its a flash cs5.5 mobile project.

Comment: Poepje, the movieclips exists indipendently on stage. one the prey is moving with accelerometer updates and the follower is required to catch that prey by as3.

Comment: Meghanshi, is it Flex then? If so, you should add the tag for it ;)

Comment: That sounds too complicated for me Meghanshi, I'm sorry. I'm afraid I can't help you :(

Comment: Poepje, its flash only. Flash cs5.5. We can deploy mobile projects with it also.